I am getting an error that OAuth2 Code has already been redeemed
def get_access_token(authorization_code):
        
    token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxcxxxxe/oauth2/v2.0/token" 
    redirect_uri = "https://localhost/api/oauth2/callback" 
    client_id = "xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx"
    client_secret = "xxxx~xxxxx~xxxx_xxxxxxxxx"
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"


    headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'code': authorization_code,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'scope': scope,
        }

    response = requests.post(token_url, headers = headers, data=token_data)
    token_json = response.json()

    if 'access_token' in token_json:
        return token_json['access_token']
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error fetching access token: {token_json.get('error_description', 'Unknown error')}")

I can't find any user information within the bearer that Microsoft provides. The token end point seems to be correct and I get all the user info within Microsoft Graph Explorer but can't on my django app.
Edit:
Changing Grant type to 'authorization_code' gives me error that OAuth2 was already redeemed. I am using Django Auth ADFS library within my Djano App where I think the code is already been redeemed. I cannot directly make changes within the Library. Is there any other way to get the OAuth2 Code?

Can you share the screenshot of API permission blade?

You are authenticating with client secret without any signed-in user, so there will be no info in token about user.

Change your grant_type to 'authorization_code'

This is the error I get after changing it to authorization_code
OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.

The error is because you are making use of Authorization code flow but passing parameter value as client credentials for grant_type.
Initially, I registered  Microsoft Entra ID Application in B2C tenant:

Granted Delegated type User.Read.All API permission:

To resolve the error modify code l:
import requests

def get_access_token(authorization_code):
    # Replace these with your actual values
    tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"  # Update this with your actual tenant ID
    token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5000"  # This must match the redirect URI configured in your app registration
    client_id = "<client_id>"  # Your app's client ID
    client_secret = "<client_secret>"  # Your app's client secret
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  # The scope for your request

    # Set up the headers and body for the token request
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',  # Use authorization_code for this flow
        'code': authorization_code,  # The authorization code received from the redirect
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,  # Redirect URI must match the one configured in your app
        'client_id': client_id,  # The app's client ID
        'client_secret': client_secret,  # The app's client secret
        'scope': scope,  # Scopes you want to request
    }

    # Make the POST request to get the token
    response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=token_data)
    
    # Parse the response and check for errors
    token_json = response.json()

    # Check if the access token was successfully obtained
    if 'access_token' in token_json:
        return token_json['access_token']
    else:
        error_message = token_json.get('error_description', 'Unknown error')
        raise Exception(f"Error fetching access token: {error_message}")

def get_users(access_token):
    # Initial URL for fetching users from Microsoft Graph API
    graph_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    
    users = []
    
    while graph_url:
        response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            users.extend(data.get("value", []))  # Add the current batch of users
            graph_url = data.get("@odata.nextLink")  # Get the next page link, if it exists
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Error fetching users: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
    
    return users

def print_users(users):
    # Print user details in a formatted table
    print(f"{'Display Name':<30} {'ID':<40} {'Email':<40}")
    print("-" * 110)
    
    for user in users:
        display_name = user.get("displayName") or "N/A"  # Safely handle None values
        user_id = user.get("id") or "N/A"  # Safely handle None values
        email = user.get("mail") or "N/A"  # Safely handle None values
        print(f"{display_name:<30} {user_id:<40} {email:<40}")

# Example usage
authorization_code = input("Enter the authorization code: ")
try:
    # Step 1: Get the access token
    access_token = get_access_token(authorization_code)
    print("Access token :", access_token)

    # Step 2: Get the list of users using the access token
    users = get_users(access_token)

    # Step 3: Print the users with displayName, id, and mail
    print_users(users)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


To get code, I ran below authorization request in browser:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/<b2c_tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
&client_id=<app_id>
&client_secret = <client_secret>
&redirect_uri= http://localhost:5000
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default



Response:



Yeah I got it grant type should be authentication_code.
The issue for me now is that my code is already being redeemed by django-auth-adfs library that I've used and it won't further allow me to use the code twice.

So then you can generate another authorization_code by sending the authorization request in browser
